# Setting up and enabling Google CSE

Tags: 7, search

Is it possible to fully set up and enable Google CSE module before a website is launched? Or would I have to wait until it's launched and submitted to Google's search engine?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set it up now but it would be much use until your content is fully indexed by Google

Answer (score 0):

Sort of doable question to answer. The answer is specif to the site that you are building. I would set up Google CSE module when I think my site has adequate contents and almost ready to go live.